# Session shared between two machines

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, iis-6

We have a shopping cart running in our test server and running into issue where the cart session is getting shared between two or more users in two different machines. In the application, user's cart gets loaded from the database and saved into the session. When the user gets to order page, his previous cart item gets loaded from saved session and any new changes in the cart gets saved in the db and also in cart session. The issue we are running into is, if there are two or more users using the application and if they add any items in the cart, the user who added cart item gets displayed to other user cart randomly. If the user refreshes the page(sometime more than one time) or navigates to different page and come back to order page, then he/she can see his/her own cart again. As i mentioned before, the cart is getting saved in session and it looks like the session is gets shared every once in a while. 
It's a legacy ASP.net application and runs in IIS6.

Does anyone ran into this issue before? Any suggestions to fix it?
Thanks.
Sanjeev

**Update: Here is what the issue was, the page was getting cached for 10 seconds through this code in aspx page.
<%@ OutputCache Duration="10" VaryByParam="none" %>
We took it out and it works as it should now.**

Comment: You can verify these..1. use session.abandon after saving session state to db, this verifies that you close session. 2. put an expiration on your cookie..Response.Cookies["userName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1); Hope this helps

Comment: This sounds unusual. Do you mean the users are on different machines (clients) or you have a web farm scenario? If the latter, you cannot use InProc Session-State mode.

Comment: @RobKent the web app is running in two web servers however when the user access it they do it through load balance url. We are using InProc Session state mode. foxtroutZulu, doesn't abandon function destroys all the session however i will need the session for my next page, so that might not work.

Comment: Does the load balancer use session affinity so that the user is always returned to the same machine once they have a session? If not, you cannot use InProc Session. If you are sure about what is happening, it seems illogical, but somehow the user is being served the wrong session. To diagnose it, set some other session value with the user's login name, for example, along with the session ID and display them on each request. That will confirm what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a StateServer to manage the state between 2 different machines.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43187/How-Do-I-Setup-an-ASP-NET-Application-to-Use-State

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/0d9dc063-dc1a-46be-8e84-f05dbb402221.mspx?mfr=true